# фильтр объекта за полученным id

Tags: javascript, json, объекты, filter

Есть объект с товарами:

```
let products = {
"11": {
    "category" : "tshirts",
    "name": "One",
    "price": 300,
    "image" : "images/tshirts.jpg"
},
"12": {
    "category" : "tshirts",
    "name": "Two",
    "price": 312,
    "image" : "images/tshirt2.jpg"
},
 "21": {
    "category" : "cups",
    "name": "Enlish cup",
    "price": 25,
    "image" : "images/cup.jpg"
},

"22": {
    "category" : "cups",
    "name": "Flower cup",
    "price": 10,
    "image" : "images/cup.jpg"
}
}
```

происходит клик на категорию и открывается контейнер со значениями товаров из объекта

```
var selected_a;

container_2.onclick = function(event) {
var target = event.target;  // find click
if (target.className != 'category_a') return; // ignore if false
open_category(target);
id = event.target.id;

 var filter = {};
 function filterProducts(products, category) { 
 for (var key in products) {
 if (products[key].category == category)
 filter[key] = products[key];
 }
 return filter;
 }
 console.log(filterProducts(products, id));

};

function open_category(node) {
if (selected_a) {
document.getElementById('product_container').style.display = 'none';
document.getElementById('container_2').style.display = 'block';
}
selected_a = node;
document.getElementById('product_container').style.display = 'flex';
document.getElementById('container_2').style.display = 'none';
}
```

но выводятся все товары с массива. Пытаюсь создать после этого новый объект с помощью filter.products, чтобы выводились только те товары, у которых category соответствует названию id, по которому кликнули. Уже много вариантов испробовано, но не срабатывает. Попытка вывести переменную event.target.id и прописать в условии фильтра не принесла результат, либо были ошибки. Как это можно сделать (буз jQuery)?

дальше идет код формирования контейнера с выбранной категорией:

```
var product_container = '';

for (var key in filtered) {
product_container+='<div class="product">';
product_container+='<div class="photo">';
product_container+='<img src="'+filtered[key].image+'" class="photo">';
product_container+='<div class="name">';
product_container+='<span class="price">$'+filtered[key].price +'</span>';
product_container+='<p>'+filtered[key].name +'<p>';
product_container+='</div>';
product_container+='</div>';
product_container+='<div class="quantity_container">';
product_container+='<span class="text_number">amount</span>';
product_container+='<div class="quantity">';
product_container+='<input type="button" data-articul="'+key+'" value="-" 
class="minus" onclick="minus()">';
product_container+='<input data-articul="'+key+'" type="text" size="10" 
value="1" class="number">';
product_container+='<input type="button" data-articul="'+key+'" value="+" 
class="plus" onclick="plus()">';
product_container+='</div>';
product_container+='</div>';
product_container+='</div>';
}

document.getElementById('product_container').innerHTML = product_container;
```

выводится здесь:

```
<div class="product_container" id="product_container">  </div>
```

после клика здесь:

```
<div class="container2" id="container_2">
<div class="block_1">
<a href="#" class="category_a" id="tshirts">
<div class="name"><p>T-Shirts</p></div>
</a>
<a href="#" class="category_a" id="cups">
<div class="name2"><p>Cups</p></div>
</a>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
let products = {
  "11": {
    "category": "tshirts",
    "name": "One",
    "price": 300,
    "image": "images/tshirts.jpg"
  },
  "12": {
    "category": "tshirts",
    "name": "Two",
    "price": 312,
    "image": "images/tshirt2.jpg"
  },
  "21": {
    "category": "cups",
    "name": "Enlish cup",
    "price": 25,
    "image": "images/cup.jpg"
  },
  "22": {
    "category": "cups",
    "name": "Flower cup",
    "price": 10,
    "image": "images/cup.jpg"
  }
};

function filterProducts(products, category) {
  var res = {};
  for (var key in products) {
    if (products[key].category == category)
      res[key] = products[key];
  }
  return res;
}

function showProductsByCategory(category) {
  var filtered = filterProducts(products, category);
  //console.log(filtered);

  var product_container = '';
  for (var key in filtered) {
    product_container += '<div class="product">';
    product_container += '<div class="photo">';
    product_container += '<img src="' + filtered[key].image + '" class="photo">';
    product_container += '<div class="name">';
    product_container += '<span class="price">$' + filtered[key].price + '</span>';
    product_container += '<p>' + filtered[key].name + '<p>';
    product_container += '</div>';
    product_container += '</div>';
    product_container += '<div class="quantity_container">';
    product_container += '<span class="text_number">Quantity</span>';
    product_container += '<div class="quantity">';
    product_container += '<input type="button" data-articul="' + key + '" value="-" class = "minus" onclick = "minus()" > ';
    product_container += '<input data-articul="' + key + '" type="text" size="10" value = "1" class = "number" > ';
    product_container += '<input type="button" data-articul="' + key + '" value="+" class = "plus" onclick = "plus()" > ';
    product_container += '</div>';
    product_container += '</div>';
    product_container += '</div>';
  }

  document.getElementById('product_container').innerHTML = product_container;
}
```

```html
<select onchange="showProductsByCategory(this.value)">
  <option value="" disabled selected>Select category ...</option>
  <option value="tshirts">tshirts</option>
  <option value="cups">cups</option>
</select>
<div class="product_container" id="product_container"> </div>
```

---

> к сожалению вариант с выпадающим списком не подходит, так как есть
>   плитка с изображениями-ссылками на категории, после клика на которые,
>   должен открываться блок с товаром

Дорогая Мария! Простите меня, если сможете, за то, что я сам не догадался про Вашу плитку (она у Вас, кстати, газовая или электрическая?). Такой профессионал, как я, должен был сразу подумать: "У Марии, наверное, плитка."

```js
document.querySelectorAll(".container2 .block_1 a").forEach(
  i => i.addEventListener("click", function(e) {
    console.log("Category: ", this.id);
    showProductsByCategory(this.id);
  })
);
```

```html
<div class="container2" id="container_2">
  <div class="block_1">
    <a href="#" class="category_a" id="tshirts">
      <div class="name">
        <p>T-Shirts</p>
      </div>
    </a>
    <a href="#" class="category_a" id="cups">
      <div class="name2">
        <p>Cups</p>
      </div>
    </a>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Получается вывести таким образом в консоль, если вставить в function(event), но не получается перебрать объект с помощью for in за пределами функции, чтобы сформировать дивы в контейнере со значениями товаров с отфильтрованного объекта

Comment: @MariaShyrokova Добавьте в вопрос немного html разметки, чтобы было понятно, как Вы выбираете категорию, и как Вы хотите показывать товары.

Comment: обновила, уже с фильтром

Comment: к сожалению вариант с выпадающим списком не подходит, так как есть плитка с изображениями-ссылками на категории, после клика на которые, должен открываться блок с товаром

Comment: @Maria Добавил в ответ.

Comment: Уважаемый Игорь! Никто не говорил, что вы должны были это знать, я лишь уточнила, так как поняла, что пропустила этот момент, и откорректировала добавленный код, и совсем не ожидала хамство и высмеивания.

Comment: @Maria Дорогая Мария! Не хотел Вас обидеть. Если Вы считаете мое дополнение хамским, не смотрите на код в ответе. Вам обязательно ответит кто-нибудь вежливый.